# Hide row instead of deleting when Delete button is pressed on the basis of 0 or 1

Tags: c#, sql, devexpress

I need to Hide the row from `Gridcontrol` instead of deleting the data from data source.

e.g when user deletes the row a query runs which inserts the 0 value in my table and Shows the table with rows whose value is not null.

I have tried using the code below. But i cant seem to run it.

```
del = 1;

ColumnView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;
view.FocusedRowHandle = user_typeTableAdapter1.Insert_del(del);
view.SelectRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
```

The error occurs that I cannot put del only in table adapter although i inserted self defined query.
This is the main problem that is occurring and i don't have so much help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, The answer to this question is as given below.**

***Actually I was inserting the value instead of updating it.
All i had to do was to run a query and execute it when delete is called.***

> Note this is to demonstrate the data deleted from gridView in Devexpress

```
    private void Delete(){
 try
        {
            conn.Open();


            ColumnView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetDataRow(view.FocusedRowHandle)["product_id"]);
            string query = "UPDATE product SET del =@product_del where product_id= @id";
            int del = 1;
            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_del", del);
            sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            sc.ExecuteScalar();
            sc.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

> Now for gridView part

```
  private void gridControl1_ProcessGridKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
            {

                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this row, it will permanently delete the data", "Delete?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    ColumnView view = gridControl1.FocusedView as ColumnView;
                    view.CloseEditor();

                    {
                        Delete();
                        view.UpdateCurrentRow();

                        product_viewTableAdapter1.Fill(allDataSets1.Product_view);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

> Now every time user delete a row it will get hidden instead of being deleted.

Actually it was requirement by a user. So i had to implement it.